# Flash CS5 api setup?

Tags: flash, facebook

I've searched through several tutorials and all over google to find out how to add the GraphAPI .SWC files into an adobe flash cs5 project.. I have tried placing it in the same folder as the project and then using import statements:

import com.facebook.Facebook; import com.facebook.utils.FacebookSessionUtil; import com.facebook.commands.notifications.; import com.facebook.commands.stream.; import com.facebook.net.FacebookCall;

But it has a problem saying the definition for these are not found. I need to figure out how to add the facebook api into my flash project and there's very little documentation at all on this subject. The only tutorials I have found use adobe flash builder 4.5 to create a "flex AIR application", which practically looks like a mix between xml and actionscript, and add the .SWC file into the libs folder in the package explorer of the flash builder program.

I'd much rather use Adobe Flash and do the GUI and animation stuff in the adobe flash cs5 project, do the actionscript code there and then just upload the .swf and index.html with the embed code to a website and then put it up on facebook. At least thats how it seems to me a flash app for facebook is done. My problem is getting past adding/linking the .SWC library file into an adobe flash project to make the facebook function calls available for use. Any idea how to do this, or is the flash builder program the only way?

If the flash builder program is the only way, how would I embed it into an html page? I've never worked with flex or flash builder so I'm pretty stumped here. I am quite familiar with flash/actionscript 3.0, C++, Java, C#, and Visual Basic.. I'm not very good with PHP so I'm looking at PHP as a very last resort.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set correctly the library path?
You need to go to Flash Settings (shift+F12), then Flash tab and settings button. Then, "Library Path" tab and the button "Browse to SWC File" and choose your api SWC.

For coding in AS3 I would recommend you to use [Flash Develop](http://www.flashdevelop.org).